# Why does an injective $R$-module homomorphism $M\to N$ preserve submodules?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, exact-sequence, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let $0\to M\xrightarrow{f} N\xrightarrow{g} P\to 0$ be a short exact sequence of $R$-modules.

I am looking at a proof of the fact that $N$ is Noetherian $\iff$ $M$ and $P$ are Noetherian.

For the forward direction, the proof states:

> Since $f$ is an injection, every $R$-submodule of $M$ can be seen as an $R$-submodule of $N$.

Why is this true?

I have tried to think of a counterexample (and failed, probably because the statement is true), but this result does not seem obvious to me at all.

**What I've tried:**

I want to show that if $I$ is an $R$-submodule of $M$, then $f(I)$ is an $R$-submodule of $N$. That is, I want to show that $f(I)$ is an abelian group under $+_N$ (which I will just call $+$) and there is a well-defined ring action $\cdot : R\times f(I) \to f(I)$ satisfying the module axioms.

i) Since $R$-module homomorphisms are abelian group homomorphisms, and those preserve abelian groups, $f(I)$ is an abelian group.

ii) Since $f$ is an $R$-module homomorphism, we can define $r\cdot f(i)=f(r\cdot i)\in f(I)$. Then $$r\cdot (f(i)+f(j)) = r\cdot f(i+j) = f((r\cdot i)+(r\cdot j))= f(r\cdot i)+f(r\cdot j)=r\cdot f(i)+r\cdot f(j),$$
$$(r+s)\cdot f(i) = f((r+s)\cdot i) = f(r\cdot i)+(s\cdot i)) = r\cdot f(i)+s\cdot f(i),$$
and I can show other module axioms similarly.

**My Questions:**

a) Is this approach correct? Are my proofs correct?

b) Is there a good intuition behind this? For example, there is clearly an injection from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, but no such injection preserves the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$. Why should I take for granted that an injection will preserve submodules?

Comment: The words "we can define $r\cdot f(i)=f(r\cdot i)$" make no sense. The image is a subset of $N$, so we already have an action of $R$ on it, simply by restricting the action of $N$. You don't have to check $f(I)$ satisfies the axioms of a module, but just check that it is a submodule of $N$. And this is easy. The question is pretty surprising, to be honest. Modules are usually far from being the first algebraic structures that you see. Usually you at least learn about groups and vector spaces before. So it shouldn't surprise you by any means that the image of a homomorphism is a submodule.

Comment: In the case that $R$ is a field (i.e. $R$-modules are just vector spaces), are you familiar with the fact that the image of a subspace under a linear map is a subspace of the codomain?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk yes, but fields seem to behave nicer than general rings in a lot of cases.

Comment: About your second point: the injection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ is a homomorphism of rings, and also a homomorphism of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. The ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are precisely the submodules of the module $\mathbb{Z}$ itself. So they are mapped to $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules of $\mathbb{Q}$. However, ideals of $\mathbb{Q}$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-submodules of $\mathbb{Q}$, not $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules. So there is no reason to expect ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ to be mapped to ideals of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @IAAW Any theorem about vector spaces which does not use the fact that nonzero scalars have multiplicative inverses must be true about modules over commutative rings in general. This is an example of such a theorem.